# How to address impossible values in a regression prediction interval?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, prediction, prediction-interval

**Background**

I've performed a regression analysis on a toy data set to predict GPA from height. I want to compute the predicted GPA value for a given height value and also compute a confidence interval and prediction interval.

**Problem**

GPA is bounded by zero and four. However, the prediction interval yields values below zero. How do I account for this? Do I simply report the lower limit as zero for the prediction interval?

---

**Here is a reproducible example:**

Toy data set

```
dat = 
data.frame(
      height = c(156.1629411, 167.915739, 188.2501108, 167.6613123,
                 179.8634014, 168.2430683, 166.2609911, 186.1590334,
                 186.7552002, 169.8816233, 159.2167348, 196.4992519, 187.0805065,
                 165.8625081, 159.1378035, 174.0839737, 180.8339255, 177.5432034,
                 182.3847225, 172.1491257, 185.5175245, 186.1120615, 167.7775462,
                 173.1352422, 183.3936887, 168.8035126, 181.5966908, 167.4639252,
                 161.9930293, 184.8793178, 165.0533253, 179.0275335, 175.9791919,
                 162.1386194, 178.3715926, 182.8343844, 171.9301423, 164.8881693,
                 175.9954692, 173.5878232, 191.1741458, 185.2264336, 168.7228944,
                 170.0931715, 166.4705149, 163.4913622, 168.3377146, 169.0275834,
                 172.8024576, 177.0402782),
         GPA = c(1.994346734, 0.451122736, 0.2973341, 0.32566434, 2.248619541,
                 1.430125354, 1.513450306, 0.742414357, 2.807780303,
                 3.054526326, 1.274308999, 3.197880391, 1.979193432, 2.444742794,
                 0.134509533, 2.67524307, 1.321918901, 2.210771798, 1.543065659,
                 1.211616817, 1.827895319, 3.706429897, 0.913881258, 2.719340897,
                 3.376699721, 1.542613448, 3.318219196, 1.974261923, 1.326355943,
                 0.06930939, 3.422201199, 2.757878463, 3.841015374, 0.461049494,
                 1.831679716, 0.619261458, 1.691201239, 1.016202713, 2.980519102,
                 2.182692289, 3.575957182, 2.236549198, 2.950673818, 1.971981723,
                 3.262345763, 0.355935121, 2.794274924, 1.705411179, 1.90692419,
                 1.80251608)
)
```

Construct linear model

```
model = lm(GPA ~ height, data = dat)
```

Predict GPA when height is 160 or 170

```
pred_dat = data.frame(height = c(160, 170))
pred_ci = predict(model, pred_dat, se.fit = T, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)
pred_pi = predict(model, pred_dat, se.fit = T, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95)

pred_ci
$`fit`
       fit       lwr      upr
1 1.510215 0.9825254 2.037904
2 1.810842 1.4943661 2.127319

$se.fit
        1         2 
0.2624491 0.1574011 

$df
[1] 48

$residual.scale
[1] 1.009869

pred_pi
$`fit`
       fit        lwr      upr
1 1.510215 -0.5877115 3.608141
2 1.810842 -0.2441505 3.865835

$se.fit
        1         2 
0.2624491 0.1574011 

$df
[1] 48

$residual.scale
[1] 1.009869
```

Comment: Given that your DV is bounded, a regular vanilla linear model with gaussian family is not appropriate. You either need to use a different family and / or transform your variable, or use a different model.

Comment: Thanks. What type of regression analysis is appropriate for a dependent variable bounded by 0 and 4?

Comment: There is no family that I know of which is bounded in 0 and 4. Maybe the simplest approach would be to transform the variable in 0 and 1, and then use fractional logistic regression or beta regression.